# FixedUpdate slightly fired up even if scene is paused with Time.timeScale = 0f

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie in unity & c# . The FixedUpdate function does some Rigidbody  action (here pushing the cube over the z axis)

However the scene works fine in development (cube starts at z = 0 )

The problem is in build , the cube starts at certain distance means z = 5 or 6

According to my understanding , I believe this is caused due to FixedUpdate being fired for some milli seconds before it notice Time.timeScale = 0f in PauseGame function

And when it notice this it behave as expected.

But then on Restart function when being called up (called by a button) using SceneManager.LoadScene function cube starts with z= 0 in build.

clip at [development](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEOyBFFdUbF8cfW9cEr4IbLj2S5YclYm/view?usp=sharing) and clip with bug at [build](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEOyBFFdUbF8cfW9cEr4IbLj2S5YclYm/view?usp=sharing)

where did I go wrong, thanks in advance.

[image: image of bug at build]

```
image of bug at build, cube starts at certain position
```

[image: image of development which working fine as expected]

```
image of development which working fine as expected cube starts at z = 0
```

```js
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tapToStart;

    private void Start()
    {
        tapToStart.SetActive(true);
        PauseGame();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        StartGame();
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }

    public void PauseGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }
    public void StartGame()
    {
        tapToStart.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
}
```

```js
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public new Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public float force;
    
    private void Update(){}

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(0, 0, force * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: "The problem is in build, the cube starts at certain distance means z = 5 or 6" Do you mean the problem is at runtime when z > 0? Or are you referring to running it in Unity Editor vs building it and running it.

Comment: Based on the post itself I have no indication as to how `Restart()`, `PauseGame()`, `StartGame()` are bound and what what is contained in the hierarchy of the scene. So all we can do is speculate rather than provide a solution. We CAN agree that starting with `Time.timeScale = 1f;` will have this side effect.

Comment: issue had been solved  :)

Comment: Why don't you just disable the player script (`enabled = false`) this way there is no need for an additional flag ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved .. I can't pause on start,
need to create a Boolean in PlayerScript.

```js
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public new Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public float force;
    public bool isGameStart; // this Boolean  
    
    private void Update(){}

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isGameStart)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(0, 0, force * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

and using that bool value , we need to use rigidbody component.

and in StartGame function in GameController we must assign true to that bool value

```js
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject tapToStart;
    public PlayerScript playerScript;

    private void Start()
    {
        tapToStart.SetActive(true);
        PauseGame();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        StartGame();
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
    }

    public void PauseGame()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }
    public void StartGame()
    {
        tapToStart.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        playerScript.isGameStart = true;
    }
}
```

this worked for me , this solution was given by a Youtuber "Unity city".. credits to him.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct! FixedUpdate is called at relatively'fixed' intervals. It doesn't matter if something is done in your other code and you need it to get updated immediately. FixedUpdate will just keep pressing on at a a regular interval.

You can verify your suspicions by placing the line:

```
rigidbody.AddForce(0, 0, force * Time.deltaTime);
```

Inside your Update() function.

Now, onto the solution. I suggest that create place the following code in your currently empty Update() function:

```
if(Time.timeScale = 0f){
    rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

Now, as soon as you press the pause button, it will be detected on the next frame of Update() and the object will be frozen. This will likely occur even before FixedUpdate is called. Of course, if you want to 'restore' the velocity and angular velocity when you unpause, you will need to store that data, and then set it back up when you unpause the game.